# Use of mapping table in Hibernate in case of @*toMany

Tags: hibernate

Can anyone please describe exact use of mapping table in case of @*tomany. I tried finding it out at multiple blogs but could not find exact answer.

Comment: Why not read the documentation rather than blogs? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html.

Comment: May be its a basic question, but cant we have structure of tables as Table1 = Table 1 PK + Table 2 PK as FK and Table2 = Table 2 PK + Table 1 PK as FK..Why we need separate tables to manage the relationship? What are the consequences if we dont use @Jointable?

Comment: To map what? Edit your question, and elaborate. Give an example. Ask a concrete question.